# Как поменять элементы массива в обратном порядке в Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Как поменять элементы массива в обратном порядке?

```
class Test {


public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. Делаете цикл от 0 до `floor(длинаМассива/2)`  - где `floor` это округление в меньшую сторону. Это нужно если количество элементов в массиве не чётное.
2. На каждой итерации меняете значение на позиции `i` с позицией на `длинаМассива - i - 1`. Можно использовать третью переменню если угодно, т.е.

   ```
   tmp = arr[i];
   arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
   arr[arr.length - i - 1] = tmp
   ```
3. Всё

---

Если имеется в виду вариант: что нужно сделать нисходящую сортировку даже в массиве, где идут значения не по порядку - тогда вам надо смотреть любые алгоритмы сортировок. Их очень много

https://academy.yandex.ru/posts/osnovnye-vidy-sortirovok-i-primery-ikh-realizatsii  , + https://habr.com/ru/post/335920/

- Сортировка "пузырьком" (как раз для новичков)
- Сортировка вставками
- Сортировка посредством выбора
- Сортировка перемешиванием (шейкерная сортировка)
- Сортировка расчёской
- Сортировка выбором
- и т.д.

---

Answer (score 0):

Для массивов объектов достаточно просто использовать сочетание методов `Collections.reverse` + `Arrays.asList`:

- `Arrays.asList` создает нерасширяемый список на основании массива, и все изменения в списке будут отражаться в исходном массиве
- `Collections.reverse` переставляет элементы *списка* в обратном порядке, соответственно изменяя расположение элементов в массиве

```java
public static<T> void reverse(T[] arr) {
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(arr));
}
```

Для массивов примитивных типов таких как целочисленные `int`, `long`, `short`, `byte`, символьный `char`, с плавающей точкой `double`, `float`, булевый `boolean` следует обменять между собой элементы в начале и конце массива.

Примерная реализация для целых чисел (без применения промежуточной переменной для перестановки элементов с использованием XOR):

```java
public static void reverse(int[] arr) { // аналогично для byte, boolean, short, char, long
    for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        arr[j] = arr[j] ^ arr[i] ^ (arr[i] = arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Для массива символов `char` дополнительно можно воспользоваться функционалом класса `StringBuilder`, в котором есть свой метод `reverse`, а также метод `getChars`, позволяющий скопировать данные из экземпляра `StringBuilder`.  В целом такой способ затратнее по памяти, так как `StringBuilder` создаст свой внутренний массив:

```java
public static void reverse(char[] arr) {
    new StringBuilder(arr.length).append(arr).reverse().getChars(0, arr.length, arr, 0);
}
```

Для массивов чисел с плавающей точкой следует воспользоваться третьей переменной для обмена значений, так как XOR для таких чисел не применим, а обмен при помощи суммы может оказаться неточным из-за погрешностей округления.

```java
public static void reverse(double[] arr) { // аналогично для float
    for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        double t = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = t;
    }
}
```